# Angular 4 property updating without any reason

Tags: angular

I would like to set `this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis;` only once during `ngOnInit()`. However, when I call this method `addSegmentsForAnalysis()` it updates the value of `this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis` to `this.segmentsForAnalysis`. What could be causing it to update?

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.segmentsForAnalysis = this.submissionDetails.segmentations.filter((segment) => {
        return segment.columns.length === 1;
      });

  this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis;
}

addSegmentsForAnalysis() {
   this.segmentsForAnalysis.push({
      name: this.fileColumn.value,
      overlapAnalysis: false,
      columns: [{
        index: segmentIndex,
        name: this.segmentTitle.value
      }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Because `this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis` points to same Object, which is getting updated in the method.

Comment: How can I set `this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis;` only once on `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: use `this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis.slice();`

Comment: That was an easy hack :)

Comment: it's not a hack. It is a standard method to have a different object based on some object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice()` method for your referenced array object to have a new set of values. It will be based on your array `segmentsForAnalysis` and it will create a new set of it. So, it won't be updated unless you call `ngOnInit` again .
<sub>*which won't happen unless you create your component again*.</sub>

So use this:

```
ngOnInit(){
 .......
    this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis.slice();
        //  add .slice here -------------------------------^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis;
When you assign viewSegmentsForAnalysis with segmentsForAnalysis then it viewSegmentsForAnalysis referncing the same object as segmentsForAnalysis. When you are changing anything in segmentsForAnalysis then obviously both variables refering to same object will definetly update.

To fix your issue you need to create a another object for viewSegmentsForAnalysis. To do this replace this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = this.segmentsForAnalysis; with

```
this.viewSegmentsForAnalysis = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.segmentsForAnalysis));
```